# How to add Home Page url key for all scopes programmatically using Recurring.php magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, programmatically, home-page, url-key

I tried to add Home Page **URL key** programmatically using **`Recurring.php`**

Normally from Magento Admin backend:

> STORES -> GENERAL -> Web -> Default Pages -> Default Web URL:

[image]

I tried using

> Vendor/Module/Setup/Recurring.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;


class Recurring implements InstallSchemaInterface
{   
    const default_web_url  = 'cms';
    protected $_configInterface;

        /**
     *  @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface
     */
    protected $configWriter;

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter
    ) {
         $this->configWriter = $configWriter;
      }

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
       $value = self::default_web_url;
       $this->configWriter->save('web/default/front',  $value, $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0);

    }
}
```

In my local, this value is storing for all store view scopes(**`$scopeId = 0`**) but in our server, it's setting value for only one store view.

This is the issue I am facing here if anyone having any idea please guide me.

> Thanks in Advance !!!!.

Comment: check out https://github.com/semaio/Magento2-ConfigImportExport it's super easy to migrate config-settings

Comment: Let me know still, your code will not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you didn't set sequence in `module.xml` file :

Replace this below code with your `module.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

I checked your code and testing. Rest of all your code working.

**Hope it maybe helpful for you.**

Comment: Why downvoted? what's wrong in this?

Comment: sorry i don't know how it's downvoted,may be by mistake it's done from my side or not but i don't wanted to do anything because even i don't have much clearity on this topic, i will appreaciate for your answer thanks for answers if it will work i will accept your answers.

Comment: Okay. No any issue :) Yes it will working.

Comment: If possible then, remove entry of your module from setup_module table and then upgrade deploy.

Comment: yes we can do upgrade deploy command but not able to delete any data from setup_module table.

Comment: oh..!! Then, maybe output will be not display. Because, after sequence add in module, we should upgrade again for maintain sortorder of module.

Comment: yes you are right it's not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96757/discussion-between-hitesh-balpande-and-rohan-hapani).